# DataStax OpsCenter 5.1.0 fails to start due to python 'ImportError'

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Trying to start a tarball installation of OpsCenter 5.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit by running ./opscenter in /opt/opscenter-5.1.0/bin fails with the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/twistd", line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
ImportError: cannot import name run`

My version of python is 2.7.6:
`$ python --version
Python 2.7.6`

And trying to import twisted results in:
`$ python -c "import twisted; print twisted"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named twisted`

The value of PYTHONPATH from opscenter looks as follows:
`PYTHONPATH: ./src:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:./src/lib/python2.7/site-packages:./lib/python2.7/site-packages:./lib/py:./lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64::`

What is going wrong here and can someone suggest a workaround that is worth  trying to a Python newbie?

Comment: Install Twisted. That's easy and fast enough for a newbie :)

Comment: It looks like opscenter comes bundled with its own version of Twisted and I get the same error after installing Twisted.

Comment: Please try `bin/opscenter -f` to run in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to missing symbolic links between the bundled python libraries. In particular, in /lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted the symoblic links to the contents of the py-unpure directory for the files _version.py, plugin.py, **init**.py and copyright.py were missing.

Originally, I used gradle's copy from tarTree to extract the archive, which resulted in the missing symoblic links. Using tar -xzf instead resolves the issue and opscenter starts up as expected.